# ngFor produces empty content - Angular 7 IVY

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I'm playing around with angular 7 and ivy, and I cannot get a for loop to spit out any values.

My code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-list',
  templateUrl: './asset-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-list.component.scss']
})
export class AssetListComponent implements OnInit {

  asset = {name: 'test'};
  assets: Asset[] = [this.asset];
  cols: any[] = [];


  colors: any[] = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']; // EDIT: added this for debug

  constructor(private assetService: AssetService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.assetService.getAssets().subscribe((value => this.assets = value));
    this.cols = [
      {field: 'name', header: 'Name'}
    ];
  }

}
```

my html:

```
<h3>Asset List</h3>

<!--DEBUG-->
{{ assets | json }}
{{ cols |json}}

<!--Does not show-->
<div *ngIf="assets.length > 0">
  Oh, its greater than 0.
</div>

<!--also does not show-->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let a of assets">
    {{a}}
  </li>
</ul>

<!--also does not show-->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of cols">
    {{c}}
  </li>
</ul>

<!--EDIT: added for debug... also does not show?-->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of colors">
    {{c}}
  </li>
</ul>

<!--ultimately, this is what I wanted, but the above don't even work-->
<p-table [value]="assets">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-asset>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{asset[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

and the output:

[image: output]

As you can see, I ripped out the `Observable` returned from the service, and it still does not work. I'd expect to see something on the screen since the debug line shows stuff. What am I missing?

I added an array of strings `colors` just for more sanity checks... that still does not display. No errors in the console.

My package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
```

I couldn't replicate in a stackblitz... problem is related to ivy I believe. That being said, [here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvhbc8).

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz reproducing this error? I did one and things are working fine - pretty sure the problem is not with your *ngFor or how you construct the variables. I'm sure you've checked, but any compile/`ng serve` errors?

Comment: I redid my code in stackblitz, but it works... can't replicate. No ng serve or ng build errors either.

Comment: My guess is that its ivy some how as I don't think that stackblitz uses ivy.

Comment: I pushed it to bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/JDELL64/imagedam/src/master/

Comment: That's too bad -- was hoping it was some silent compile error. It has to be something up with Ivy, though I'm not seeing any active issues with `*ngForOf`

Comment: Yah... I removed Ivy, and it started working... no idea what the cause was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same exact issue when running the `--experimentalIvy` flag in a new CLI project.

I've also created an issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30081

With that said,
I've tried to update core and cli to the next version using:

```
ng update @angular/core@next @angular/cli@next
```

And it works on V8.0.0-beta.14, so...I'm not sure someone will fix it in version 7 while 8 is close to release.

Also created a Github repo with separated branches for easy reproduce, you can check it here: https://github.com/eliraneliassy/ivy-ngfor-bug

Comment: I'd say if it's fixed in 8, then that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to access a property using the dot operator inorder to see the output, otherwise it will be just **`[Object Object]`**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let a of assets">
    {{a.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxuttz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Unfortunately, that also displays nothing. Additionally, why wouldn't any of the other divs work?

Comment: did you check the stackblitz? probably you are showing us different code then